# Build Spring Boot demora muito para compilar?

Tags: java, spring

Estou fazendo um exemplo usando o Java com Spring, estou usando o Intellij IDEA, ele demora muito para compilar, estou usando o TomCat, mostrar muita mensagem no servidor, tem como configurar para ser mais rápido?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com ser mais rápido?

Comment: Digo que demora demais o processo de compilação, mostrar muitas mensagens, queria reduzir isso e ser mais rápido

Comment: Quanto eh demais pra voce? Se for algo em torno de 30s pra buildar e 1m pra subir entao estah normal.